# problem to sum optional values from v-model in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component

in this function i want to show what left from amount

```
 remainingAmount: function() {
            return parseFloat(this.sumAmount) - (parseFloat(this.cash) + parseFloat(this.kNet) + parseFloat(this.kNetOnline));
        }
```

three parameter cash and knet and knet online are came from v-model, if one of them be null retuen result being NAN ! how can i defined these v-model as optional in this function?

Comment: Would [shortcircuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation), like `this.cash||0` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

i can not find any optional function in js so i solved with conditions:

```
            var a = this.cash ?  parseFloat(this.cash) :0
            var b = this.kNetOnline ?  parseFloat(this.kNetOnline) :0
            var c = this.kNet ?  parseFloat(this.kNet) :0
```

but i think is not working for large scale data